# There is an infinity of bijections between I and J of $C^\infty$ class.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I don't know if between 2 open intervals $I$ and $J$ ,exist infinitely many  function $f$ with 
properties: 1) $f$ is a bijection, 2) $f\in C^\infty$.
I tink the answer is yes, because  we can  parametrized a curve in infinitely many ways and we know if $r_1(t)$ and $r_2(s)$ are tow diferite parametrizations $\exists f $ bijection ,$f\in C^\infty$ s.t $r_1=r_2\circ f$. But how we can rigorously proof if answer is yes?

Comment: What is infinitely many for you? At least a countable number of different functions?

Answer (score 2):

There are infinitely many (even uncountably many) $C^\infty$ bijections from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)$, eg.
$$
\varphi_a(x) = x^a, \quad \text{for all } a > 0.
$$
For any other bijection you can use it as a reparametrization: if
$$
f:\ I\to (0,1), \quad g:\ (0,1)\to J
$$
are bijections [Edit: $C^\infty$ bijections], then so are all functions
$$
g\circ\varphi_a\circ f: \ I\to J.
$$
Edit 2: there were supposed to be open intervals.

Comment: wait we don't need $f,g \in C^\infty$ to proof $g\circ\varphi_a\circ f: \ I\to J$

Comment: Yes, sorry. But we need that to make sure the composition is $C^\infty$.

Comment: If you can proof me : $\forall I \exists $ a $C^\infty $ bijection $f$ s.t $f:\ I\to (0,1)$ i'll be done.

Comment: Try it by yourself first. Hint: for finite intervals these are linear functions, for infinite and half-infinite intervals use tangent function.

Comment: if $I=(a,b) f=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$ right?

Comment: Yes, well done first half.

Comment: ok thank you man!

Answer (score 1):

The collection $\{ax+(1-a)x^3 : a\in (0,1)\}$ is an uncountable set of polynomial bijections from from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1).$ Each of these polynomials is also a bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R.$